# iOS compilation, warnings, and format strings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, warnings, string-formatting

I'm under Xcode 4, and using aggressive warnings to identify potential issues in code. The code has C, C++, and Objective C elements. The warning flags in effect are:

`-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wstrict-overflow -Wformat=2 -Wformat-security -Woverloaded-virtual -Wreorder -Wsign-promo -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wstrict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-unused-parameter`

I'm getting some noise out of a Google library. The warning is "format string is not a string literal". For example in the statement that includes the streamType:

```
NSString *streamTypeTemplate = @"multipart/related; boundary=\"%@\"";
NSString *streamType = [NSString stringWithFormat:streamTypeTemplate,
  partBoundary];
```

Does anyone have any ideas to quench this warning. I kicked it to Google but they did not fix it. I don't want to back off the warnings because I might lose a real warning in the process.

I think my solution is to fix it locally. For example:

```
NSString *streamType = [NSString stringWithFormat:
  @"multipart/related; boundary=\"%@\"",
  partBoundary];
```

But I would welcome something that does not require me to copy/paste the format string and delete a statement. Plus, the Google repo is an external repository and may complicate merging if they touch the code later.

For what its worth, a "clean compile" is a security gate. I **don't** want to teach developers its OK to back off warnings because we don't want to deal with them. It sets a horrible precedent and leads by counter-example.

Jeff

Comment: If you git cherry-picked it, it wouldn't be a problem.  Or you could always just fork it.